# If we have a matrix $X$ that is invertible, does it imply $X^{T}X$ is invertible and vice versa?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $X$. I am wondering if there is a lemma that relates invertibility of $X^{T}X$ to $X$ itself. Is it true that if $X$ is invertible, then $X^{T}X$ is invertible as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean matrix $X.$

$X$ is invertible $\iff det (X) \ne 0$

$det (X^T) = det(X)$
and

$det (AB) = det (A) det(B)$

And you should be able to put those together to prove your proposition.

Comment: Would this be an if and only if proof?

Comment: I haven't given you a full proof.  But, I have given you enough information, that yes,  you should be able to prove it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $X$ is invertible, then $X^T$ is invertible because both are bijective as linear transformations; in particular, the column rank of $X$ is equal to the column rank of $X^T$. It follows that $X^TX$ is invertible, and its inverse is $X^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: Would this be an if and only if proof?

Comment: @user321627 I am not sure I understand your question, but $X$ is invertible if and only if its transpose is invertible.

Comment: @user321627 Also, if $X^TX$ is invertible, then so is each of $X$ and $X^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is invertible.

Then $X^{T}Xy=0\implies y^{T}X^{T}Xy=0\implies (Xy)\cdot(Xy)=0\implies Xy=0\implies y=0$,

so $X^{T}X$ is invertible.

Comment: Is there a way to also prove the opposite direction by using the null property of invertible matrices above? Is it valid to say: Suppose $X^{T}X$ is invertible, then only solution to  $X^{T}Xy=0$ is $y=0$. $Xy = 0 \implies X^{T}Xy=X^{T}0 = 0 \implies y=0$? thanks!

Comment: Additionally, may I ask how did you get that $y^{T}X^{T}Xy=0 \implies (Xy)\cdot(Xy) = 0$? I know that $y^{T}X^{T}Xy = (Xy)^{T}Xy$ but dont know how it turns into the inner product. thanks!!

Comment: Your argument for the converse is fine, and I'm using that $z^{T}w=z\cdot w$.